# Content Type and Hidden Fields Becoming Visible After Workflow Update

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, content-type

I have a content type with some hidden fields which I am using in my workflow to update/maintain data but I noticed that as soon as the column is updated using workflow this field become visible and users are able to see this field in the Edit Form.

Is this a correct behavior?  Any suggestions / workaround for using the hidden fields in the workflow without showing them to users?